# Delta notation in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, notation

I have come across the notation $|A\Delta B|$ in a combinatoris course, but I am still not clear about what this means. The best I have found is [here on page 2](https://tartarus.org/gareth/maths/notes/iii/Combinatorics_2010.pdf), from which I think $\Delta$ takes the set of all elements that are eithr in $A$ or $B$ but not the other?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference

Answer (score 3):

$A\Delta B = (A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$.